# "Zweitafelbild" in English

Tags: geometry, translation-request, mathematical-german

1) How can "Zweitafelbild" and "Zweitafelprojektion" be translated into English?

Here is the Wikipedia page (in German): https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweitafelprojektion

2) In the Wikipedia article it is written that that "Zweitafelprojektion" is one of the fundamental methods of descriptive geometry, yet such a fundamental concept has no other language options. This seems to be a trend in German Wikipedia regarding many mathematical concepts. Why is that so? Are some German mathematical concepts fundamentally different from their English counterparts? Is there an attempt to keep a more German version of mathematical language which at times is not truly compatible with English?

Comment: Zweitafelprojektion seems to be just referred to as Monge projection.

Comment: Try also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Descriptive_Geometry/Understanding_Views.

Comment: I think this may be what you're looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_projection

Answer (score 1):

Looking up the translation of each component of this obviously compound word:

Zwei = two

Tafel = blackboard (plane)

Bild = image

Thus "an image on multiple planes", which the comments identify as a multiview or Monge projection.

Answer (score 0):

In a German [presentation from the University of Duisburg-Essen](https://www.uni-due.de/imperia/md/content/cad/introcax-bachelor-ws2007-v1.pdf) I have found *two-view projection* as the translation of *Zweitafelprojektion*.